# Java Swing trying to add a stationary JButton over a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane, jlayeredpane

I am trying to make a text editor with a button that appears at the bottom right of the editor regardless if you scroll up or down and appears over the text area

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Problem{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Setting up the frame
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setSize(600, 400);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Making the LayeredPane
        JLayeredPane LP = new JLayeredPane();
        LP.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //Making the ScrollPane and JTextArea
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(100,50);
        textArea.setText("Test Text");
        JScrollPane back = new JScrollPane();
        back.setViewportView(textArea);

        //Making the panel that appears in the front of the text
        JPanel front = new JPanel();
        front.setLayout(null);
        front.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        front.setOpaque(false);
        JButton button = new JButton("test");
        button.setBounds(200,200,50,20);
        front.add(button);

        LP.add(back,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        LP.setLayer(back,0,0);

        LP.add(front,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        LP.setLayer(front,1,0);

        window.add(LP);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I am seeing just the JButton with a white background, if I don't add the second layer "front" I see my back JScrollPane with the JTextArea

Comment: `LP.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` isn't going to work for you, as it will only allow a single component (the last one you added) to be managed at each available position.  I tried using a `GridBagLayout` and while it "initially" worked, if your scroll the scroll pane, the button disappears - not sure, but the scroll pane wants to be on top

Comment: 1) Swing doesn't handle background with transparency. See: [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information. However, in your case there is no need to set the background because you are using full transparency, so you just need setOpaque(false). 2) I see you are attempting to build on you last solution from your last question. I really have no idea why you are attempting to do this. I would be frustrated with a button on top of my text area. Swing does not handle stacking of component in this manner very well.

Comment: Maybe you could use a [Glass Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html).

Comment: Without knowing more, I might encourage you to make use of the "corner component" support of `JScrollPane` - [How to Use Scroll Panes: Providing Custom Decorations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#decorations)

Comment: Further on, I "think" it has to do with how the `JScrollPane` optimisations work when you scroll, but I'm not going to spend a lot of time trying to figure it out

Answer (score 2):

Swing is designed/optimized  to display/paint components in 2 dimensions. The vast majority of layout managers will make sure that the components don't overlap.

This means that you can't use a layout manager on your layered pane (if you want the components to overlap). Instead, you must manually set the size/location of components on each layer.

When you use a JLayeredPane the painting of components on each layer is managed so that the higher layer is painted last.

So your code might be changed to something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setSize(600, 400);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Making the LayeredPane
        JLayeredPane LP = new JLayeredPane();

        //Making the ScrollPane and JTextArea
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20,40);
        textArea.setText("Test Text");
        textArea.setSize( textArea.getPreferredSize() );
        JScrollPane back = new JScrollPane( textArea);
        back.setSize( textArea.getSize() );

        JButton button = new JButton("test");
        button.setBounds(200,200,50,20);

        LP.add(back, new Integer(0));
        LP.add(button, new Integer(1));

        window.add(LP);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

There is one layout manager in the JDK, the `OverlayLayout`, which is designed to stack components on top of one another. However, even this layout manager does not paint components properly when the components overlap. The trick when using this layout manager is to override the  `isOptimizedDrawing()` method of the panel using the layout manager to make sure all components are repainted all the time. In this case, make sure the bottom panel is always painted before the top panel.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Main2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()
            {
                return false;
            }
        };
        contentPane.setLayout( new OverlayLayout(contentPane) );

        JPanel top = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
        top.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 16, 16) );
        top.setOpaque(false);
        top.setAlignmentX(1.0f);
        top.setAlignmentY(1.0f);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;

        JButton button = new JButton("test");
        top.add(button, gbc);
        contentPane.add(top);

        //Making the ScrollPane and JTextArea
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10,25);
        textArea.setText("Test Text");
        JScrollPane back = new JScrollPane( textArea);
        back.setAlignmentX(1.0f);
        back.setAlignmentY(1.0f);
        contentPane.add(back);

        window.add(contentPane);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that the button will move as the frame is resized.

However, as a user I would still get annoyed with a button appearing over top of the text in my text area.

Edit:

If you really need components to overlap then I would suggest you could:

1. look at MadProgrammers solution to use a GridBagLayout. This approach gives far more control over the alignment of the components
2. check out the [Overlap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/) which also provides more flexibility when aligning overlapping components

It should be noted that both above approaches may still require you to override the `isOptimizedDrawEnabled(...)` method to make sure components are painted properly. I am not aware of any layout manager the allows you to overlap components and works without this override.

Comment: The first approach sucks - put more text in and it just won't scroll

Comment: @MadProgrammer - both approaches scroll fine for me using JDK11 on Windows 11 using either the mouse or Page Up/Down keys.  I don't like either approach for a UX, but it does answer the question. Maybe a Glass Pane will work better.

Comment: On MacOS your first approach won't allow me to scroll beyond the first page of results (but the layout is so screwed up anyway), the second approach seems to work okay

Comment: Okay, I got something to work using your `isOptimizedDrawingEnabled` idea and just `GridBagLayout`, which, I personally, prefer, but I still don't think it's a very good UX (looking at you Google ) (personal opinion)

Comment: @MadProgrammer *but I still don't think it's a very good UX* - neither do I which I have already stated three times.  Once in my original comments to the question and again in my answer and comments here. Hope the OP gets the hint. Are you suggesting you used a layered pane with multiple panels each using a GridBagLayout? If you got something working why not post it. Maybe it is not the best UX for this, but it might work for other requirements.

Comment: Essentially what I got working was your `isOptimizedDrawingEnabled`, but instead of using a `OverlayLayout`, I used a `GridBagLayout` for the `contentPane`

Answer (score 2):

## Caveat

I'm not a fan of this is idea.  It's not a "common" UX concept that many desktop users would be presented with and there are a number of, arguably, better solutions which leverage the pre-existing experience of users.

This requires some "hacking" to get to work, so, there's no guarantee that it will work on all platforms or continue to work into the future.

## Why doesn't it work?

This is a rather technical question which delves deep into the core of how Swing, and in particular, the `JScrollPane` work.  Let's just say, I don't have the time or desire to dig into, but I know the `JScrollPane` is heavy optimised, which may be affecting the way in which anything which overlays it gets updated - or it could just be the way that the painting system works.

## Runnable example...

This takes the idea by camickr (all credit to him), but instead of using a `OverlayLayout`, makes use of a `GridBagLayout` to position the button.  Why?  Because the `GridBagLayout` gives me more control over the position of the button - it's a personal thing.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(40, 40);
            try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/StarWarsNewHope.txt"))) {
                textArea.read(reader, "A long list");
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
            JButton button = new JButton("Am I in your way yet");

            JPanel contentPane = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled() {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1.0;
            gbc.weighty = 1.0;
            // Change this to reposition the button some where else
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(32, 32, 32, 32);
            gbc.ipadx = 16;
            gbc.ipady = 16;
            contentPane.add(button, gbc);

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1.0;
            gbc.weighty = 1.0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
            contentPane.add(scrollPane, gbc);

            add(contentPane);
        }

    }
}
```

You should probably also look at [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and the section on [Providing Custom Decorations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#decorations) for some alternatives

Comment: (1+) I'll need to remember this. The trick is to add the two components to the same grid. The GridBagConstraints then give more control on how the components are aligned within the grid than can be achieved with the OverlayLayout.